# How to assign path in bindProperty correctly?

Tags: sapui5

I created an `sap.m.ObjectIdentifier` object and the properties are bound to a path as following:

```js
const oObjectIdentifier = new ObjectIdentifier();
oObjectIdentifier.bindProperty("title", {
    path: "{Objects>Object}"
});
oObjectIdentifier.bindProperty("text", {
    path: "{Objects>Objecttext}"
});
```

and it is the aggregation of a [`Tree`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Tree) table:

```js
this.byId("ClassObjectTable").bindItems({
    path: "Objects>/",
    template: oColList
});
```

Earlier, I've done as following:

```js
const oObjectIdentifier = new ObjectIdentifier({
    title: "{Objects>Object}",
    text: "{Objects>Objecttext}"
});
```

and it worked.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```js
> oObjectIdentifier.bindProperty("title", {
>   path: "{Objects>Object}"
> });
> ```
>
> What am I doing wrong?

The syntax of the `path` value is invalid. Remove the curly brackets:

```js
oObjectIdentifier.bindProperty("title", {
  path: "Objects>Object"
});
```

[API reference: `ManagedObject#bindProperty`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindProperty)